# How add two values[1,2 elements] and verify its equal to result[3 element]

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to verify if the sum of two elements is equal to the result shown on the UI.
Below is the html structure for the three elements and need to do the calculation on the h1 tags.
[image]

Below is the code I am trying to execute but nothing comes up in the test. The test runs and passes but nothing in the body.

```
it.only(' Verify Sum Of Active and Paused Jobs is Equal To Total Jobs Count ', () => {
    function activejobnumber() {
    return cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryActiveJobsStatTitle"]>h1')
    .invoke('text').then(parseInt).as('actnum');
      
    }

    function pausedjobnumber() {
      return cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryPausedJobsStatTitle"] > h1')
     .invoke('text').then(parseInt).as('pasnum');
      
    }
    function add() {
      const totaljobs = activejobnumber() + pausedjobnumber();
      cy.log(totaljobs);
    }
  });
```

Also, if someone could point out why it isn't working, would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly invoke text, convert them to numbers and add it like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryActiveJobsStatTitle"]>h1')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((actnum) => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryPausedJobsStatTitle"] > h1')
      .invoke('text')
      .then((pasnum) => {
        //Adding + converts string to number
        const totaljobs = +actnum + +pasnum
        cy.log(totaljobs)
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Using functions to encapsulate each number is fine, but remember that commands inside are still asynchronous, and they are not returning numbers, they are returning Chainers.

If you did it without functions, this is what it would look like

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryActiveJobsStatTitle"]>h1')
  .invoke('text').then(parseInt).as('actnum')
  .then(actnum => {

    cy.get('[data-cy="jobSummaryPausedJobsStatTitle"] > h1')
      .invoke('text').then(parseInt).as('pasnum')
      then(pasnum => {
 
        const totaljobs = actnum + pasnum
        cy.log(totaljobs)
      })
  })
```

so with functions you need to repeat that pattern

```js
function add() {
   activejobnumber().then(actnum => {
     pausedjobnumber().then(pasnum => {
       const totaljobs = actnum + pasnum;
       cy.log(totaljobs);
     })
  })
}
```

or take advantage of the alias for each number

```js
function add() {
  activejobnumber()
  pausedjobnumber()

  // wait for above async calls to finish
  cy.then(function() {          
    const totaljobs = this.actnum + this.pasnum;
    cy.log(totaljobs);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but if i am using `const totaljobs = actnum + pasnum` it's not adding the numbers but putting the togther I need 5+4=9 it's giving me 54 instead.

Comment: You missed out the `.then(parseInt)` section (you already have it in the original functions) - that will convert text into number and allow math addition instead of text concatenation.