# How to adding values from dynamic elements and verifying the result

Tags: javascript, cypress

Similarly to this question. [How add two values[1,2 elements] and verify its equal to result[3 element]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355419/how-add-two-values1-2-elements-and-verify-its-equal-to-result3-element/73357930#73357930)

from the below HTML structure I need to add A(element) & B(element) and verify the sum is equal to A+B(element) its complex for me since A & B are dynamic and they can or cannot be present depending on the changes from the user.

[image]

I tried to use the below script.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="Selected in Final InterviewofferBreakUpTableBodyCellRenderer"] >span').invoke('text')
```

But it's yielding both the text, i only need the number.

[image]

I need help in making a test that won't fail even if only one element A or B is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Final Interview Selects')
  .next()
  .invoke('text')
  .then((sum) => {
    cy.contains('span', 'Selected - Not Offered')
      .next()
      .invoke('text')
      .then((A) => {
        cy.contains('span', 'Selected in Final Interview')
          .next()
          .invoke('text')
          .then((B) => {
            expect(+sum).to.eq(+A + +B)
          })
      })
  })
```

You can do something like this if some of the elements are not visible.

```js
const A = 0,
  B = 0
cy.get('body')
  .then(($body) => {
    if (
      '$body:not(:contains("Selected - Not Offered"))' &&
      '$body:contains("Selected in Final Interview")'
    ) {
      A = 0
      cy.contains('span', 'Selected in Final Interview')
        .next()
        .invoke('text')
        .then((num) => {
          B = +num
        })
    }

    if (
      '$body:contains("Selected - Not Offered")' &&
      '$body:not(:contains("Selected in Final Interview"))'
    ) {
      B = 0
      cy.contains('span', 'Selected - Not Offered')
        .next()
        .invoke('text')
        .then((num) => {
          A = +num
        })
    }

    if (
      '$body:not(:contains("Selected - Not Offered"))' &&
      '$body:not(:contains("Selected in Final Interview"))'
    ) {
      A = 0
      B = 0
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.contains('span', 'Final Interview Selects')
      .next()
      .invoke('text')
      .then((sum) => {
        expect(+sum).to.eq(A + B)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Does this handle the dynamic nature of `Selected - Not Offered` & `Selected in Final Interview`

Comment: Do you mean these texts might change in future? Or do you mean the associated values like Sum, A and B?

Comment: `Selected - Not Offered & Selected in Final Interview` wont be visible if the number is 0. if in future `Selected - Not Offered' is 0 only `Selected in Final Interview` visible be shown on the front end vice verse.